# What is the proper way to use the Prime typesetting in an integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I've got an integral I'm trying to calculate in Mathematica:

$$\tau(\eta)=\int_0^\eta n_e\sigma_T a\space d\eta\prime$$

My best attempt to represent that in Mathematica has been:

```
OpticalDepth[η] := Integrate[ne[eta] σT a[eta], {eta, 0, η}]
```

It works, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to write this.  Using the full spelling of `eta` seems amaturish in this language.  Ideally, I'd like to see this:

```
OpticalDepth[η] := Integrate[ne[η'] σT a[η'], {η', 0, η}]
```

But, of course, `'` is the derivative function.

Comment: I personally use nothing but ASCII characters in my code if I can help it. Even though the capabilities are there for fancier things, the headaches that they can cause when copy/pasting code aren't worth it.

Comment: ASCII?  Who uses ASCII anymore?  Is that even an option?

Comment: As in `a-Z` `1-9`, and not the `\[Rho]` type characters as much.

Comment: What is the question here? How to type greek letters or how to improve prime typesetting (as title suggests)? First is: <kbd>Esc</kbd>+rho+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, found in the Documentation easily at any greek letter. Second: I cannot understand the question.

Answer (score 4):

I would likely write your function definition as

```
opticalDepth[η_] := Integrate[ηe[u] σT a[u], {u, 0, η}]
```

because a single letter variable like `u` is easy to type. To avoid problems with a previous top-level assignment to `u`, you can write it with a guard:

```
opticalDepth[η_] := Block[{u},Integrate[ηe[u] σT a[u], {u, 0, η}]]
```

However, using a formal symbol which cannot have an assignment may appeal to you as more elegant.

```
opticalDepth[η_] := 
  Integrate[ηe[\[FormalEta]] σT a[\[FormalEta]], {\[FormalEta], 0, η}]
```

This looks much better in a Mathematica notebook:

[image: def]

`\[FormalEta]` can be typed in as <kbd>esc</kbd>+<kbd>$Eta</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>

Comment: Note: in M12  dots show up only at the bottom when one uses \[Formal] which is more cool I guess.